# Pygame pong game

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I am trying to get the ball object to bounce around inside the screen, I have been testing different things for hours, looking at other pong game source code and other questions on here but I just can't seem to figure it out. Could someone give some pointers on where to start? Should I make separate functions for the different movements?

```
    # ----- Game Loop ----- #

# Setting the loop breakers
game_exit = False

# ball positon/velocity
ball_x = DISP_W/2
ball_y = DISP_H/2
velocity = 5

# Game loop
while not game_exit:
    # Gets all events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Close event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # Closes game loop
            game_exit = True

    # Background fill
    GAME_DISP.fill(black)

    # Setting positions
    ball.set_pos(ball_x, ball_y)
    # ceil.set_pos(0, 0)
    # floor.set_pos(0, DISP_H - boundary_thickness)

    ball_y += velocity



    # Drawing sprites
    ball_group.draw(GAME_DISP)
    # collision_group.draw(GAME_DISP)

    pygame.display.update()

    # Setting FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

# ----- Game exit ----- #
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

FULL CODE: http://pastebin.com/4XxJaCvf

Comment: It would help if you explained what happens, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I would like it to bounce off the ceiling and the floor, moving diagonally, right now i am simply just trying to get it to bounce off the floor and the ceiling moving in a straight line...

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the pygame sprite class. It has a lot of handy methods to help with collisions and other stuff: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html